# Why does raspbian come with so many versions of python?

Tags: raspbian-stretch

I was editing my start menu in Raspbian, when I found out that my version of Raspbian (installed via NOOBS) came with **6** (8 if you count Thonny) versions of Python!

I get why it came with Python 2.7 and 3.5, but why does it have 3 duplicates of themselves?

Image for visual reference:

[image: raspbian start menu]

I think these extras are useless and it should come with only Thonny, IDLE 2.7 and 3.5.

I have a RPi 3 Model B running the latest version of Raspbian Stretch

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lots of Software in Debian still needs Python 2.7 for the forseeable future. Raspbian is based on Debian and therefore has the same dependencies. Python 3 is of course supposed to be the only correct choice for new software ... sigh.

What you are seeing are 2 "IDEs" for Python, plus a shortcut to Python's REPL. There are only two distinct Python versions pre-installed on Raspbian, and Python would be fine enough on the commandline and running invisibly in the background. As the Raspberry Pi was designed for computer education of children of school going age (that is where most of the foundation money goes) those 6 shortcuts are just to make it trivial to start programming in Python.